# Segmenting data by percentage of a column total

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I need to separate a list of records by the percentage of a column when they are summed to all records larger than the current record until a `MAX` percentage.

Records are sorted `DESC` in column A, and I need all rows in A summed up until (from large to small) they equal 60% of the sum(A) (col B). Then, I need to perform the same for the rest of the row to 30% of the sum(A), and then the last 10% or the rest of the records.

The top 60% records need to be marked as A, middle 30% records marked B and last ~10% marked C.
I have tried `NTILE` but can't get the segments to match up correctly.

```
╔══════════════════════╦══════╦═══╦══════╦═════╗
║            A         ║   B  ║ C ║      ║     ║
╠══════════════════════╬══════╬═══╬══════╬═════╣
║     197              ║  197 ║ A ║      ║     ║
║     192              ║  389 ║ A ║      ║     ║
║     190              ║  579 ║ A ║      ║     ║
║     185              ║  764 ║ A ║      ║     ║
║     184              ║  948 ║ A ║      ║     ║
║     184              ║ 1132 ║ A ║      ║     ║
║     181              ║ 1313 ║ A ║      ║     ║
║     180              ║ 1493 ║ A ║      ║     ║
║     175              ║ 1668 ║ A ║      ║     ║
║     172              ║ 1840 ║ A ║      ║     ║
║     171              ║ 2011 ║ A ║      ║     ║
║     170              ║ 2181 ║ A ║      ║     ║
║     169              ║ 2350 ║ A ║      ║     ║
║     169              ║ 2519 ║ A ║ 2602 ║ 60% ║
║                      ║      ║   ║      ║     ║
║     167              ║  167 ║ B ║      ║     ║
║     167              ║  334 ║ B ║      ║     ║
║     167              ║  501 ║ B ║      ║     ║
║     166              ║  667 ║ B ║      ║     ║
║     166              ║  833 ║ B ║      ║     ║
║     166              ║  999 ║ B ║      ║     ║
║     165              ║ 1164 ║ B ║ 1301 ║ 30% ║
║                      ║      ║   ║      ║     ║
║     164              ║  164 ║ C ║      ║     ║
║     164              ║  328 ║ C ║      ║     ║
║     163              ║  491 ║ C ║      ║     ║
║     163              ║  654 ║ C ║  867 ║ last
║                      ║      ║   ║      ║     ║
║     TOTAL A:A = 4337 ║      ║   ║      ║     ║
╚════════════════════=╩═════════╩══════╩═════╝
```

Comment: `60+30+20 ?= 100` Nice.

Comment: @ypercube - the percentages are going the "opposite way" cumulatively to what one would expect. AFAICS - 20% of 4337 is 867.4 ~ 867, 30% is 1301.1 and 60% is 2602. It's confusing, I know but I think that's what he means in that table?

Comment: @Vérace ok for those numbers but still. It seems that 60% (or a bit less) rows are marked with A and 30% (or a bit less) are marked with B. So, it should be about 10% (or a bit more) rows marked with C. Which is exactly what happens, 58% in A, 27% in B so there are left 15% for C. The 60-30-20 does not make sense.

Comment: Yes, this is a typo in my column formula, the last segment should be 10%. the previous records need to sum to less than 10% of the SUM(A).  I can make this work fine in excel but my data is in oracle and I would like to do it in oracle.

Comment: @ypercube: Agree, the 60-30-20 split seems nonsensical, but if you take a case like `158, 157, 156, 155, 154, 153, 152, 151, 150`, then the first group will have a little more than 56%, second 22%, leaving for the third one slightly less than 22%.

Comment: @AndriyM we could make numbers like `401, 201, 101, 100, 99, 98` that would give 40%, 20% and 40% Still the same (only the bits chopped from A nd B and given to C are large ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the percentage of the sum of `a` you've reached up till the current row, then segment that based on your thresholds.

```
with pct as (
  select a
  , (sum(a) over (order by a desc))/sum(a) over() pct
  from foo
)
select a
, pct
, sum(a) over (partition by
    case
      when pct <= .6 then 'A'
      when pct <= .9 then 'B'
      else                'C'
    end
    order by a desc) partial_sum
from pct
order by a desc;
```

Expanded version that actually shows the category (second subquery isn't necessary, just avoids repeating the partial sum expression):

```
with pct as (
  select a
  , (sum(a) over (order by a desc))/sum(a) over () pct
  from foo
), category as (
  select a
  , pct
  , case when pct <= .6 then 'A'
         when pct <= .9 then 'B'
         else                'C'
    end cat
  from pct
)
select a
, cat
, to_char(pct*100, '999.99')||'%' pct_of_total_a
, sum(a) over (partition by cat order by a desc) sum_by_category
from category
order by a desc;
```

Comment: Hum... there's an issue with this query though, not sure if that's a problem for you: if there are very few rows (e.g. 1), or if you have unbalanced values (say 1 row a = 100, and 10 rows a = ~1; or 1 row a=75 and 1 row a=25) you probably won't get the categories you expect. If that's a problem, could you edit the question to say what you would expect in those cases?